# How do I store Java Methods in a List in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I want to keep a list of normalizing functions for a text. How do I store .toLowercase?
I was thinking of something like this:

```
(def normalizing-functions (list remove-punctuations .toLowerCase))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your making a list of functions to apply to something on a regular basis. the java method is not quite a clojure function in this sense though its really 
easy to wrap it up just like you would if you where going to feed it to the map function.

```
#(. tolowercase %)
```

Comment: That worked! Is there a documentation for these operations? Thanks.

Comment: This is an anomymous function, also sometimes called a lambda.
#(. toLowerCase %)) is a reader macro that is shorthand for (fn [x] (.toLowerCase x)).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than keeping them in a list which you'll have to unpack some way later, it may just be easier to wrap `.toLowerCase` in a clojure function (edit: using my or Arthur's syntax) and compose it with the functions you're planning to use to normalize your data using `comp`:

```
user=> (defn remove-punctuation [st] ...removing puncutation mechanics...)

user=> (defn lower-case [st]
         (.toLowerCase st))

user=> ((comp remove-punctuation lower-case) "HELLO THERE!")
"hello there"

user=> (defn normalize-data [data]
         ((comp remove-punctuation lower-case) data))
```

Comment: Thanks but I cant do that for all of my functions. That is a nice hack anyways.

Answer (score 1):

The `memfn` macro will do this in a more readable way.

```
(def f (memfn toLowerCase))
(f "Hello")
```

would return "hello". `(doc memfn)` has the details.